# windriver automation using batch

Tags: batch-file, automation

I'm trying to automate src files copy, open windriver, import project, close, reopen and compile on windriver.

So far I've managed to copy the files, and to open the windriver IDE. `(START ...\windriver.exe)`
My problem currently is how to insert a string to the windriver prompt: [image]

I tried to add the string as an argument but that failed.
Is this possible using batch? and what about my next steps? (import project from within windriver, and compile)

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with GUI applications.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what windriver is but I can tell you so much: batch can't interact with any GUI. You can't make a batch file click buttons, type text or do anything like that.

However, many applications have command line support. E.g. starting internetexplorer.exe with an URL as a parameter will start the browser and open the passed URL. However, each applications has its own commands it supports. Often you can find out which options are supported by starting the program from the cmd console and adding `/?` or `-?` or `/h` or `-h` or `/help` or `-help` the call (like `SomeApplication.exe /?`).

But it's also possible that windriver doesn't support any cmd parameters. In this case, you'll have to automate the GUI. To do so you'll have to use more advanced tools like AutoIT (which would I prefer), VBScript or Sikuli (there are many different script languages for GUI automation).